# No puedo mostrar las fechas en un mismo embed con python desde discord BOT

Tags: python, discord.py

He creado un bot para discord que muestra todas las fechas de cualquier  skin de fortnite a traves de la api, pero mi problema esque no me muestra todas las fechas dentro del embed con el comando !skin, sólo me muestra una fecha en formato timestamp

este es el código:

```
@bot.command()
async def skin(ctx):
    url = requests.get("https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=palito%20de%20pescado%20de%20gominola&searchLanguage=es")
    historialSKIN= url.json()
    
    for i in historialSKIN["data"]:
     for datestr in i['shopHistory']:
        fecha = int(isoparse(datestr).timestamp())

    embed=discord.Embed(title="Titulo", description=f"{fecha}")
    embed.add_field(name="Skin", value="skin", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Qué deberia de hacer para que muestre todas las fechas en un mismo embed?

[image]

Deberia de quedarme asi:

[image]

Muchas gracias antemano!

Comment: Vos mismo estas convirtiendo la fecha a timestamp. Si isoparse devuelve un objeto date, convertir eso en cadena deberia de crear una fecha tal y como esperas. Tldr: prueba quirando .timestamp()

Comment: Sobre poner varias fechas. Deberias de elegir otra seccion del embed. No creo que un titulo sea lo que buscas.

Comment: Es en description

Comment: Entiendo. En ese caso, probaste la propuesta que te hice en mi primer comentario de quitar .timestamp()?

Answer (score 1):

Mi respuesta es similar a la de [@Jabro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/306873/jabro) solo que uso `strftime` y `strptime` en una lista comprimida para darle formato al texto de la fecha:

```
import datetime

@bot.command()
async def skin(ctx):
    url = requests.get("https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=palito%20de%20pescado%20de%20gominola&searchLanguage=es")
    historialSKIN= url.json()

    fecha = [datetime.datetime.strptime(datestr, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for i in historialSKIN["data"] for datestr in i['shopHistory']]

    embed=discord.Embed(title="Titulo")

    embed.add_field(name="Shop history", value='\n'.join(fechas), inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Ocurences", value=len(fechas), inline=True)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

la variable almacena lo siguiente:

```
>>> fecha
['2021-10-16', '2021-10-17', '2021-10-18', '2021-10-19', '2021-10-20', '2021-10-21', '2021-10-22', '2021-10-23', '2021-10-30', '2021-10-31', '2021-11-01', '2022-10-10', '2022-10-11', '2022-10-12', '2022-10-13', '2022-10-14', '2022-10-15', '2022-10-16', '2022-10-30', '2022-10-31', '2022-11-01']
```

para agregar la imagen debes usar una instancia de [`embed_image`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object-embed-image-structure), chequea la sección de preguntas frecuentes [como agregar una imagen](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#local-image). Tambien el método `set_thumbail` sirve para mostrar la imagen en la parte superior derecha `embed.set_thumbnail(url="image_url")`, la dirección url de la imagen [`historialSKIN["data"][0]['images']['featured']`](https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/cid_a_226_athena_commando_m_sweetteriyakired/featured.png).

Answer (score 0):

En tu código tienes:

```
for i in historialSKIN["data"]:
    for datestr in i['shopHistory']:
        fecha = int(isoparse(datestr).timestamp())
```

En cada iteración del bucle, estás sobrescribiendo el valor de la variable `fecha`, por lo que cuando añades a la descripción del embed la variable `fecha`, esta solo contiene la fecha de la última iteración del bucle.

Lo que tienes que hacer para solucionarlo es crear una lista y, en cada iteración del bucle, añadir la fecha a la lista de fechas:

```
fechas = []

for i in historialSKIN["data"]:
    for datestr in i['shopHistory']:
        fechas.append(int(isoparse(datestr).timestamp()))

embed=discord.Embed(title="Titulo", description=f"{'\n'.join(fechas)}")
```

En cuanto al contenido de las fechas, dado que no sé a que módulo pertenece el método `isoparse()`, no te puedo dar una solución que use dicho método. Una solución alternativa sería:

```
for i in historialSKIN["data"]:
    for datestr in i['shopHistory']:
        fecha = datestr.split('T')[0] # Puede producir IndexError, gestiónalo como consideres
        fechas.append(fecha)
```